# Trying to set up mailing button VB

Tags: mailing

I have an Email button but I cant get it to work it is doing notng and i don really know why.

> `Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbsEmailRenewal.Click
>           On Error GoTo Err_cmdEMailInvoice_Click

```
    If tbsEmailRenewal.Tag = "" Then Exit Sub

    ' Create Report
    Dim ListReport = New FastReport.Report
    ListReport.Load(My.Settings.SystemPath & "\Reports\EmailRenewalLetter.frx")
    ListReport.SetParameterValue("CRMConnectionString", "Data Source=" & My.Settings.SQLServer & ";AttachDbFilename=;Initial Catalog=ICOM.Database;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=CRMUser;Password=S0rtmypc!")
    ListReport.SetParameterValue("MemberID", objMember.MemberID)
    ListReport.Prepare()

    ' Create Export File
    Dim PDFExport As FastReport.Export.Pdf.PDFExport = New FastReport.Export.Pdf.PDFExport
    ListReport.Export(PDFExport, My.Settings.SystemPath & "Reports\EMailReport" & Format(objMember.MemberID, "00000") & ".pdf")

    ' Create EMail 
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMailMessage As Outlook.MailItem
    objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    objMailMessage = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
    With objMailMessage
        .To = txtEmailAddess1.Text
        .Subject = "Renewal For " & lblMemberIDValue.Text
        .Attachments.Add(My.Settings.SystemPath & "Reports\EMailReport" & Format(objMember.MemberID, "00000") & ".pdf")
        .Display()
        .Save()
        .Close(Outlook.OlInspectorClose.olDiscard)
    End With
    objMailMessage = Nothing
    objOutlook = Nothing

    ' Log It
    Dim sMessage As String
    sMessage = Replace(">" & Format(objMember.MemberID, "00000") & " to " & tbsEmailRenewal.Tag, "'", "`")
    WriteAuditLogRecord(Me.Name, "tbsEmailRenewal.Click", "INFO", sMessage)
    MsgBox("Email has been saved as a Draft", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "ICOM - Action Confirmed")

 Err_cmdEMailInvoice_Click:


   If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    sErrDescription = Err.Description
    WriteAuditLogRecord(Me.Name, "cmdEMailInvoice_Click", "Error", sErrDescription)
    MsgBox("System Error occurred" & Chr(13) & "tbsEmailRenewal.Click" & Chr(13) & sErrDescription, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "AztecCRM - Error Reporting")
End If
End Sub`
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that tbsEmailRenewal.Tag is not empty?

```
If tbsEmailRenewal.Tag = "" Then Exit Sub
```